# Maven: Error while executing goal versions:update-properties

Tags: maven-3, versions-maven-plugin

I am running the command `mvn versions:update-properties` but I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven plugin:2.1:update-properties (default-cli) on project <project>: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \uef (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \uef... @1:1)
```

I already found a ticket in the Maven-JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2057) which was fixed in Maven version 2.0.8, but I'm using Maven 3.2.5. What's the deal with this? And how to avoid such an error without avoiding the update-properties?

Platform information via `mvn -version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to a solution for this problem. The `pom.xml` was encoded with UTF-8 with BOM. The problem was solved after converting the file to UTF-8 w/o BOM.